# How to accumulate (stock) result of (flow) query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a query that sums if account is credit and subtract it if debit:

**Query Number 1 - Flow**

```
SELECT year(data), month(data), 
    (
        SUM(IF(Credito='Conta Corrente Itau', valor, 0))-
        SUM(IF(Debito='Conta Corrente Itau', valor, 0))
    )
AS Fluxo    
FROM base
GROUP BY YEAR(data), MONTH(data)
```

It works just fine and I get something like this:

```
2015    4   -9.999999999996362
2015    5   0.059999999997671694
2015    6   -139.6999999999971
2015    7   140.15999999999804
2015    8   466.85999999999876
2015    9   -81.24999999999818
2015    10  -525.2499999999991
```

This is perfect, except I'm trying to accumulate the result so it gives me the balance, instead of the flow of a specific account.

Found a query that accumulates

**Query Number 2 - Cumulative**:

```
SELECT data, base, (@total := @total + base) AS ValorTotal
FROM (
    SELECT data,
    SUM(VALOR)
    AS base 
    FROM base
    WHERE
        (debito="Conta Corrente Itau")
    GROUP BY YEAR(DATA), MONTH(DATA)
    ) AS T,
(SELECT @total:=0) AS n;
```

But it is a bit unclear on where should a put the whole (working) **Query Number 1** code above inside the cumulative query in order to have the balance of an account.

Tried replacing the whole SELECT statement from Query 2, but got an `unknown column 'data' in field list` error:

```
SELECT data, base, (@total := @total + base) AS ValorTotal
FROM (
        SELECT year(data), month(data), 
            (
                SUM(IF(Credito='Conta Corrente Itau', valor, 0))-
                SUM(IF(Debito='Conta Corrente Itau', valor, 0))
            )
        AS Fluxo
        FROM base
        GROUP BY YEAR(DATA), MONTH(DATA)
    ) AS T,
(SELECT @total:=0) AS n;
```

Does anybody have any idea on how could I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use aliases for columns from your subquery.
For example:

```
SELECT Y,(@total := @total + Fluxo) AS ValorTotal
FROM (
        SELECT year(data) AS Y, month(data) AS M, 
            (
                SUM(IF(Credito='Conta Corrente Itau', valor, 0))-
                SUM(IF(Debito='Conta Corrente Itau', valor, 0))
            ) AS Fluxo
        FROM base
        GROUP BY YEAR(DATA), MONTH(DATA)
    ) AS T,
(SELECT @total:=0) AS n;
```

The subquery with alias `T` return only columns with names `(Y,M,Fluxo)` and you can use only them.

Comment: wow, worked like a charm! thanks a lot! I confess I don't quite understand what's going on on the code, but I'll take a better look on how aliases work... anyway, thanks!

Comment: It's easy to understand. The subquery returns a new rowset (for the final query it's like a new table) and you give new names for all the columns from this new recordset. The query `SELECT * FROM (your subquery) AS T` looks as `SELECT * FROM T`. Good luck!